# How to insert ruby command prompt to ruby mine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, command-line, rubymine

Earlier, a question was asked about inserting a terminal directly into Ruby Mine on Windows.  It was answered but only to a certain extent.  I understand how to get cmd.exe to open in Ruby using settings, but how do you get the ruby command prompt to open? My cmd.exe doesn't work with ruby, I have to use this path which won't work with the instructions given earlier.

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby193\bin\setrbvars.bat

Thanks!

Comment: either include the link to the previous question or copy some text, we have not a clue what you are referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to "Tools" and then "Run Rails Console"

**"Tools" >> "Run Rails Console"**